# Game Object Appears in Scene View but not in Game View

Tags: unity-game-engine

Seems like I am missing something here, using latest version of unity and I am instantiating a gameobject on click.. It appears fine in scene View but not in the game view?

I have googled it and tried all those responses.

I checked the layers at the top right of the screen, They are all showing, Also the z value is lower than the cameras' But honestly i have tried having them at nearly all z positions.

The game object i am spawning is a sprite with a rigid body, but that shouldn't matter right? It shows up in scene view and game view should just show me what the scene does?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is a pretty old question but I just had the same issue. I solved it by playing around with the camera clipping planes.

To test if this is the case, hit play and when the object is supposed to be in view, hit pause.

Select the camera from the hierarchy and try altering the clipping planes - "Near" and "Far" properties from the inspector.

If this works then don't forget to make the same changes again after the game has stopped running - They reset to the way they were before you hit play.

I think this is to do with the distance from the camera that objects have to be,  in order to be rendered. Its probably useful with fog etc. but I'm kinda new to Unity so could be wrong.

I tried posting a screenshot but apparently you're not allowed to help properly if you're new on here :s. probably to prevent spam etc.

Anyway, hope this helps someone out there :)

[image: Unity Screenshot]

Comment: If you post a link to a good, cropped screenshot, someone will usually notice you in the first posts triage queue and edit your post (or propose an edit) to show the screenshot inline in place of the link.

Comment: Thanks for the info Palu. unfortunately I made the image myself when I realised you could post images so no link actually exists. It shouldn't be too difficult to spot though.

Comment: Thanks for responding regardless that it is old.

Comment: thanks man clipping planes work out , i had set near to 0 and far 1000 in unity 5.6

Comment: Thanks for the response! this fixed my issue as well

Comment: WE HAVE A WINNAH!!!!!

Comment: Would like to know why I have to do this a lot now, though.

Answer (score 11):

It can happen for may problems

**1. Culling mask problem:**

just check it, it is set to everything or not

[image: Culling Mask]

**2. Far Near problem:**

Solve it by changing their values. I can't say about any specific values cause it varies from problem to problem

[image: Far near Problem]

**3.Layer Problem:**

this problem specially happen when you a create a new scene on unity but it can happen for many reasons

To solve this

- Click on layers
- Set everything visible

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7):

On the Inspector of your MainCamera or Camera, you will find something called "depth", just set it to the same value as your field of view and it will work :)

Comment: Thanks for this, hopefully it helps someone

Answer (score 5):

By default in a 2D scene the camera is pointing to positive Z and it is located at (0 1 -10). This means that the Z position of the sprite needs to be higher than cameras Z position, not lower.

Also check that Sprite Renderer of the sprite is enabled in the "Inspector" view.

If those doesn't help I would suggest starting to remove other GameObjects at run time to see if the sprite is behind something. Just click on a GameObject at "Hierarchy" view and hit delete key.

Hopefully some of these help you to find the problem.

Comment: sorry for delay, It seems i have found the problem, It seems the camera is really zoomed in? but the white box which is supposedbly the camera outline covers my whole scene and the rest of the scene displays correctly... just the camera that is looking at my instantiated items is zoomed in? but in the scene view they display as normal size. any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried changing the `Field of View` of the camera?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your instantiated object or the object making the instantiations is not behind the camera. Check this by clicking scene view while your game is running and then clicking the 2d in top right corner, see if your objects spawn behind camera.