# How to fix camera to show background in unity 3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

i have the following background and the following main camera , here is the main camera : http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/681386Untitled1.png
the preview is looks like this : http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/479945Untitled2.png

i don't get the background and the player in the main camera
please help me solving this problem
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your camera's position's Z value is 0, which means your gameobject and camera is on the same plane, so camera can not view it. Change it with some negative value (try -10).

Answer (score 0):

I recently answered a camera problem here so I would check to see if this helps...

[Game Object Appears in Scene View but not in Game View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28469186/game-object-appears-in-scene-view-but-not-in-game-view/31432924#31432924)

If not, I can see a few warnings occurring at the bottom of the screen shot you posted in Unity, it might be worth addressing those problems first (regarding HDR and rendering paths).

Not sure if this will fix the issue as there isn't a huge amount of info available on your post so it could be a whole range of problems.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks the probleme was in the position of the camera Z must be -10